# Upgrade airflow image version on google cloud Composer

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

When I first created an instance on GC Composer, it was set on airflow 1.9.0. Since the time, the images 1.10.0 and 1.10.1 are now available for new composer instances, but I didn’t find a way to upgrade into an existing composer instance !

What is the best way to upgrade ?

Answer (score 1):

**Image version is a non-editable property of cloud composer.**

The only way is backup your files in bucket or cloud shell environment.Then delete and [rebuild](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/creating)(select the version you need and copy back the files).

Comment: Can I backup the airflow database to just continue jobs with saved states

Comment: No you cannot, once you recreate composer jobs will be started as fresh

Comment: If the same airflow version is used, this could be helpful: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/migrating.